# Tablespace when creating index in oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, tablespace

What is the difference of assigning a tablespace to an index in oracle vs not assigning any tablespace in creation? Are there any advantages or disadvantages? If there are advantages, is there any way of knowing which is the best tablespace that can be assigned to an index?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify tablespace while creating index, it will be created in default tablespace for that user.

By default, there are several tablespaces in your database. For example, in my 11gXE:

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL>
```

As you can see, there's no tablespace whose name "sounds" like "index". But, you can create one, if you want. Quite a few years ago, it made sense to separate data from indexes, putting them into their own tablespaces onto different hard disks, hoping for better performances. To answer your question: which tablespace is "best"? The one you'd create for indexes.

However, nowadays, with fast, modern servers, it is not to be done because Oracle takes care about *everything*. Some people say that they enjoy being DBAs, watching Oracle administering itself.

Therefore, just `CREATE INDEX` and don't worry about the rest.

Comment: I have 3 available tablespaces: tab_2k, tab_8k and tab_16k. I am trying to optimize a query and depending to which tablespace I assign the index the number of consistent gets is higher or lower. The best case is when I assign the index to the tab_16k. The latter case is better than the default tablespace assigned. I would like to know why it is better for some tablespaces than other.

Comment: Purely guesswork, but I would expect `tab_2k` to use a 2048 byte pagesize, `tab_4k` to use a 4096-byte pagesize, and `tab_16k` to use a 16384 byte pagesize. I'd expect an object on `tab_16k` would require require about 1/8th the number of physical I/O's as would that same object on `tab_2k`. YMMV.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica That comment probably should be clarified, as it makes it sound like `tab_16k` is unconditionally better than `tab_2k`.  If you are reading an index for a 40 byte entry, you'll load and keep 16k into the buffer cache instead of 2k.  So, fewer I/Os on average yes, but probably more wasted RAM.